# Jquery Multiple Sortable List

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui-sortable, draggable, droppable

Can someone please explain how to take the code below.

Heres a screen shot

[alt text http://img196.imageshack.us/img196/9514/picture4omk.png](http://img196.imageshack.us/img196/9514/picture4omk.png)

this is my JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 

    $(function() {
        $("#sortable1, #sortable2").sortable(

            { connectWith: '.connectedSortable', 
            opacity: 0.6, 
            cursor: 'move', 
            update: function() {
            var order = $(this).sortable("serialize"); 
            $.post("home/updateBOX", order, function(theResponse){
                $("#contentRight").html(theResponse);
            });                                                              
        }                                 
        });
    });

});
```

This is my current View

```
<div id="contentLeft">
    Category 1
    <ul id="sortable1" class="connectedSortable">
    <?php foreach($getcat1->result() as $box) :?>

            <li id="recordsArray_<?php echo $box->boxID ?>"><?php echo $box->boxID . ". " . $box->boxID . $box->boxText ?></li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
    Category 2
    <ul id="sortable2" class="connectedSortable">
    <?php foreach($getcat2->result() as $box) :?>

        <li id="recordsArray_<?php echo $box->boxID ?>"><?php echo $box->boxID . ". " . $box->boxID . $box->boxText ?></li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

This is my current Controller

```
function index()
    {

        // Boxes
        $this->db->order_by('boxListingID','ASC');      
        $this->db->where('boxListingCat',1);
        $data['getcat1'] = $this->db->get('boxes');

        $this->db->order_by('boxListingID','ASC');
        $this->db->where('boxListingCat',2);
        $data['getcat2'] = $this->db->get('boxes');


        // Initialize
        $this->layout->set('nav', $this->class);
        $this->layout->load('layout','home/home_view',$data);
    }   

    function updateBOX()
    {
        if (empty($_POST))  { return false; }
        $updateRecordsArray = $_POST['recordsArray'];
        $listingCounter = 1;
        foreach ($updateRecordsArray as $listingCounter=>$recordIDValue) {
            $this->db->set('boxListingID',$listingCounter+1)->where('boxID',$recordIDValue)->update('boxes');
        }

    }
}
```

Please Help!

I have been trying very hard to make the following code work so that when you are dragging a li from one UL to another it will detect that it's in a new UL and save that data. I don't know where to start

I will be very very appreciative for any help.

Answer (score 4):

What about using the **draggable** and **droppable** plugins in **[jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/home)**?

The [Draggable plugin](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/) makes selected elements draggable by mouse.

the [Droppable plugin](http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/) provides a drop target for draggables.

Answer (score 0):

Yup! Draggable and Droppable should do the trick... You can use the **[drop()](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Droppable#event-drop)** method of droppable to update the list state for both.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/Waw4V/2/

If you're looking to make multiple sortables, it is best done by attaching classes to each kind of list. The above link uses divs, but you can apply it to lists.

Lets say you have a list of questions:

```
<div id='questionList'>
    <div class='question'>
        <div>Question Details</div>
        <div class='answerForQuestion'>
            <div class='answer'>Answer 3
                <span>Details</span>
            </div>
            <div class='answer'>Answer 2</div>
            <div class='answer'>Answer 4</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class='question'>
        <div>Question Details</div>
        <div class='answerForQuestion'>
            <div class='answer'>Answer 2</div>
            <div class='answer'>Answer 7</div>
            <div class='answer'>Answer 11</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's what you do in jQuery:

```
$('#questionList').sortable(); // this makes one each major category sortable
$('.answerForQuestion').sortable({  // this makes sub categories sortable
    connectWith: ['.answerForQuestion']
    change: // this fires everytime the item you drag is moved, put in your logic here, such as an ajax call to update your database
});
```